# is it possible to use selenium web driver for AngularJS site?

Tags: protractor

We have very good Automation framework already in place which is in java/selenium to verify our web application but now our site will be migrated to Angular and we do not want to move to protractor. So shall we use selenium for Angular app ?

Comment: https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver - May help you out in using existing java code to test angular app. Though protractor re-write would be the best option...

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium for Angular app but it is more suitable  to use the protractor for Angular app testing, as it is built in framework for the Angular app.